# jquerys load not loading html page properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I got a  main view like this,

```
<body>
 <div id="view"></div>
</body>
```

The problem is if I inject an HTML content to this div it is not working, but when I copy paste the elements between the body tag its working.

I have included a jsfiddle of my script and partial : https://jsfiddle.net/whb65L5w/7/

It does some preprocessing of data to be populated on the body as well as the partial. But using jquerys load function the page is not working properly, can someone tell me why.

This is how i load the partial:

```
$( "#view" ).load( "views/sales.html" );
```

You can see that even though I selected items, it's not being checked

[image]

Comment: Need to close your div.

Comment: sorry, forgot to close it while posting the question. But thats not the issue am facing

Comment: Should I be getting `nv is not defined`? :)

Comment: sorry, its just the code to have an understanding, its not working fiddle. What I can't figure out here is why is the code not working when am injecting using load, and why is it working directly, thought it had to do something with other functions in script or the order in which they are executed. But that doesn't explain why radio buttons are not working

Comment: Yeah, I understood afterwards. :) Just for fun, I've made this elementary fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pm99opu9/ - so there is no tricky functionality you're missing from your description. If you can provide the code - would be really helpful.